# How to use correctly setFocusable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use setFocusable and set to true after a valid click, but sometimes it happens in the wrong way. What should be changed to work properly?

```
if (m.matches()) {
               // after do below command. I think is always false due to nothing happend
     editText.setFocusable((!editText.isFocusable()));
               // below comands makes that afther first click in log is true, after second click false and it repeats.
     Log.e("isFocusable",String.valueOf(!editText.isFocusable())); 
     return  true;
} else {
     editText.setError("BlaBla Error");
     editText.setFocusable(true);
     return false;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what m.matches() return

Comment: The problem only concerns in a situation when m.matches return true.

Comment: when exactly you are facing the problem? when changing setFocusable() value false to true or when changing it true to false?

Comment: On second click. When I should change true to false.

Comment: I don't know. Button may be clicked on VM and on mobile also touched(maybe simply). You suggest on mobile should be ok?

Comment: No. what i am saying is, if you placed the code inside a OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener, one simple click may cause more than one execution of this.

Comment: I placed the code inside OnClickListener. More precisely using onclick param in xml. Maybe it is important - editText is inside inflanted fragment to activity.

Comment: **First click path of editText is:** 

android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{43da794 VFED..CL. .F...... 498,0-996,144 #7f0e00b0 app:id/etDistanceView}
**Second click path of editText is**

android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{43da794 V.ED..CL. ........ 498,0-996,144 #7f0e00b0 app:id/etDistanceView}
**Third click path of editText is:**

android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{43da794 VFED..CL. ........ 498,0-996,144 #7f0e00b0 app:id/etDistanceView}